# Is a question about a problem that might be caused by a virus "on topic"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753634/cannot-execute-python-and-always-shows-gpython-exe) yesterday and didn't really think much of it. I just did a tag removal of the irrelevant tag the OP used. But looking back at the question, the accepted answer says that he has a virus on his PC.

Should the question remain on Stack Overflow even though the problem and "solution" (used very loosely) in my opinion don't meet the criteria of on-topic questions defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

So long story short: Should I have flagged it as off topic or have just left it?

Comment: The close-reason _“This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. […]”_ would fit here, probably, which would make it off-topic.

Comment: @Xufox unfortunately i dont think i have that option

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a virus. A virus would do far more insidious things. More likely, OP has an issue with their file associations, as one commenter observes.

Comment: In any case a guess is not an answer (but it is an attempt to answer...), so downvoting is very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's first sentence is:

> Something strange happened on my computer and I don't know why. I
>   can't execute my python file

The description is very general and vague, and unlikely to help someone else in the future. This post is useless for OP and for everyone else that may come across it.

The post is poor, and should be closed. I voted to close [for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming.

Comment: Python and gpython are definitely tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: @S.L.Barth This doesn't make the problem related to programming. If you're unable to open a tool on your computer, it doesn't necessarily mean it's related to programming.